# Windows allocates less power for background windows, is that a setting I could change?

Tags: windows, performance, window

So I am developing a multiplayer game and I generally need to run multiple simultaneous instances of it for testing.

The current foreground window, the active window is the one that's gonna run at the most frames per second, while the other ones will be way lower, even lower than my monitor Hz.

If i click anywhere on the desktop to de-select the window, all windows will appear to get the same FPS but still far from native performance. Almost like windows thinks they are not important, they look like a slideshow.

is there somewhere i can change that?

Comment: As the author of the program you have direct control of your application when it’s in the foreground and background.  If it’s a slideshow that’s due to the design of your application more than likely

Comment: its a unity game, might research on that i guess.